# Is there a way to animate alpha of rgba background without jquery.color?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, alpha, rgba

I need animate background with jQuery's animate() from `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)` to `rgba(255,255,255,0.9)` without using jquery.color plugin & changing of CSS opacity.
The background color is always the same (white), I need animate only rgba's **alpha**.
Any suggests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pre-made CSS class with the required animation, and then use jQuery to toggle that class on/off.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/syoels/moL1q6ea/

```js
$('#button1').click(function() {
  $('.square').removeClass('fadeMeIn').addClass('fadeMeOut');
});

$('#button2').click(function() {
  $('.square').removeClass('fadeMeOut').addClass('fadeMeIn');
});
```

```css
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.fadeMeOut {
  -webkit-animation: faeOutRGBA 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: faeOutRGBA 1s linear;
  -o-animation: faeOutRGBA 1s linear;
  animation: faeOutRGBA 1s linear;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.fadeMeIn {
  -webkit-animation: faeInRGBA 1s linear;
  -moz-animation: faeInRGBA 1s linear;
  -o-animation: faeInRGBA 1s linear;
  animation: faeInRGBA 1s linear;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
@-webkit-keyframes faeOutRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes faeOutRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes faeOutRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes faeOutRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  ;
}
@-webkit-keyframes faeInRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes faeInRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes faeInRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes faeInRGBA {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
  }
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square"></div>
<button id="button1">fade out</button>
<button id="button2">fade in</button>
```

Comment: It could actually be a lot shorter - but i put in cross-browser support for the animation

Answer (score 1):

```
var $obj = $('.selector');
$obj.css({volume: 50});
$obj.animate({volume: 90}, {
    duration: 200, // default 400
    step: function (n, t) {
        $(t.elem).css({background: 'rgba(255,255,255,'+n/100+')'});
    }
});
```

[jquery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

and maybe you need also:

```
if (!$obj.is(':animated')) {
    $obj.animate(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use css opacity. In fact jQuery's animate() uses it too.

Comment: That won't affect just the background's opacity unfortunately

Comment: @Molecule, @PaulPRO: in this case I need to change opacity to 1 instead of 0.9, right?

Comment: @PaulPRO, I don't know ways to change just the background's opacity. However, it might be done with ugly hacks like adding extra div with same size, needed background, and positioned behind target block using absolute positioning and zIndex.

Comment: @Ken, yes. And don't forget that if you want it to be crossbrowser you have to apply some [tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for example?

http://jsfiddle.net/YZKKp/13/